# PageIndexChanging function not being called when I change page number in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Dear Stack Overflowers,

I have a gridview in the front end page and here it is in asp.net code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdManufact" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" 
    GridLines="Horizontal" AllowPaging="True" OnRowDataBound="manufGridView_RowDataBound"                             EnableModelValidation="False" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" HorizontalAlign="Center"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdManufact_SelectedIndexChanged" OnPageIndexChanging="grdManufact_PageIndexChanging">
  <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="SrNo" HeaderText="SrNo" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Manufacturer" HeaderText="Manufacturer" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="isModerated" HeaderText="Approved" />
     <asp:BoundField />
```

Well that is the main part of it but it displays correctly and binds correctly upon page load.
Whenever I change page to page 2 or 3 or whatever of the gridview, my gridview disappears! I have tried putting a breakpoint in the PageIndexChanging function but the breakpoint is not reached which tells me that the event is not even firing and yet the gridview just disappears. Here is my backend function Page Index Changing anyway:

```
protected void grdManufact_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdManufact.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGrid();
}
```

And the BindGrid() function used to bind the grid :

```
public void BindGrid()
{
    string strConnectionString =   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);    // Connect to database
    conn.Open();                                                    // Open Connection
    string com = "select ManufacturerID as SrNo, ManufacturerName as Manufacturer,        ManufacturerDescription as Description,isModerated From VehicleManufacturer";
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, conn); // Select all manufacturers in the table
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();                                 // Create a new Data Table
    adpt.Fill(dt);                                                  // Fill it with manufacturers
    grdManufact.DataSource = dt;    // Make the datasource of the manufacturer grid the new table
    grdManufact.DataBind();                                         // Bind data for the grid
    conn.Close();                                     // Close database connection. Disconnect
}
```

Here is my page load in case you wanted that too:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)                            // If this is the first time loading the page through postback
        BindGrid();                             // Bind the Manufacturers to the gridview
    else
    {
        ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
        if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "Button2_Click")
        {
            //call the method 
            btnDelete_Click(this, new EventArgs());
        } 
    } 
}

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction to fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True"` property if you need to excute server side page index changed event or set it `false`

Answer (score 1):

I remember that this happen if you set `EnableViewState = false`. Make it `EnableViewState  = true` ! If the grid disappears on every postback just put the binding in `if(!IsPostBack)` in Page_Load method.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)                            // If this is the first time loading the page through postback
            BindGrid();                             // Bind the Manufacturers to the gridview
        else
        {
            ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
            if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "Button2_Click")
            {
                //call the method 
                btnDelete_Click(this, new EventArgs());
            } 
        }
    }

Comment: @SolimanSamirSoliman add the Page_Load method in the question, it will be easier for others to see it.

Comment: Also removing the else statement in the code above makes no difference, the gridview is still disappearing.